# Same Testing Accuracy for Pruned model and Original model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model-comparison

I am trying to perform model pruning on ResNet50. However, I am getting exactly the same testing accuracy on both of them. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
import numpy as np

prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude

# Compute end step to finish pruning after 2 epochs.
batch_size = 128
epochs = 50
validation_split = 0.1 # 10% of training set will be used for validation set. 

num_images = x_train.shape[0] * (1 - validation_split)
end_step = np.ceil(num_images / batch_size).astype(np.int32) * epochs

# Define model for pruning.
pruning_params = {
      'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.50,
                                                               final_sparsity=0.80,
                                                               begin_step=0,
                                                               end_step=end_step)
}

model_for_pruning = prune_low_magnitude(model, **pruning_params)

# `prune_low_magnitude` requires a recompile.
model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
import tempfile
import os
logdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

callbacks = [
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep(),
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.PruningSummaries(log_dir=logdir),
]
```

```
model_for_pruning.fit(x_train, y_train,
                  batch_size=batch_size, epochs=5, validation_split=validation_split,
                  verbose = 1,
                  callbacks=callbacks)
```

```
_, baseline_model_accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
_, model_for_pruning_accuracy = model_for_pruning.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print('Baseline test accuracy:', baseline_model_accuracy) 
print('Pruned test accuracy:', model_for_pruning_accuracy)
```

Output:
Baseline test accuracy: 0.9070000052452087
Pruned test accuracy: 0.9070000052452087

Comment: Are you certain that the model has been pruned? Is there any difference in baseline and pruned models?

Comment: No, it is not getting pruned. I am not able to understand why. The code is the same as that in the TensorFlow documentation.

Comment: Is it possible that the pruned model replaces the original model instead of creating a new pruned model? That why both the models are the same.

Comment: Can you provide a model summary? Not sure if you have prunable layers.